# CSS issue with Chrome 61

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm using a custom horizontal rule CSS style on my site. It looks like the following:

[image: Styled HR in Firefox]

But since I have updated my Google Chrome to version 61 the line height of the symbol is ignored and it looks like this:

[image: HR in Chrome 61]

I'm using the following code:

```
hr {
    background: #ccc;
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    line-height: 1 !important;
    margin: 20px 0;
    text-align: center;
    clear: both;
}
hr:after {
    content: '\f0c4';
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: -10px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    background: #fff;
    color: #ccc;
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `overflow` property seems to have a new default value on the `<hr>` element.

It looks like the value changed from `visible` to `hidden`, so the icon is hidden. You can add `overflow:visible` to the `<hr>` element to show your icon again.

```css
hr {
  background:#ccc;
  border:0;
  clear:both;
  height:1px;
  line-height:1 !important;
  margin:20px 0;
  overflow:visible;
  text-align:center;
}
hr:after {
  background:#fff;
  color:#ccc;
  content:'\f0c4';
  display:inline-block;
  font-family:'FontAwesome';
  font-size:20px;
  padding:0 10px;
  position:relative;
  top:-10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<hr/>
```

> **Hint:** I recommend you to use [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) to avoid such an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please change `position:relative` to `position:absolute` and `top:10px`.

```css
hr {
    background: #ccc;
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    line-height: 1 !important;
    margin: 20px 0;
    text-align: center;
    clear: both;
}

hr:after {
    content: '\f0c4';
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    background: #fff;
    color: #ccc;
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<hr>
```

Comment: and now add some content before the `<hr>` ;)